# Can't set properties in ember after promise succeeds

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

When the promise succeeds and I attempt to set a property of the controller using `this.set('propertyName', value)` I get the following error regarding the set method:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Qlovi Reader</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search"{{action 'updateInfo' on="submit" }}>
          <div class="form-group">
            {{input value=attemptQuestionSet type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="37297"}}
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        {{#if currentUser}}
          <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Signed in as {{currentUser.userName}}</p>
        {{/if}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
      {{outlet}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Application Controller:

```
 App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
  currentQuestionSet: null,
  actions:{
    updateInfo: function(){
      this.store.find('questionSet', parseInt(this.attemptQuestionSet)).then(function(questionSet){
        this.set('currentQuestionSet',questionSet);
      },function(){
        alert("Question Set not found");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Is there a new scope once the promise succeeds or other issues regarding scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you have to assume callbacks (not just promises, all callbacks) will lose the value of the `this` pointer unless documentations specifically says otherwise. This behavior is because the caller is what determines what `this` points to, and in this case the caller is the `then` function in whatever promise library Ember is using.

The solution is to capture `this` in a closure, like so:

```
 App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
  currentQuestionSet: null,
  actions:{
    updateInfo: function(){
      var self = this; // Store away current this
      this.store.find('questionSet', parseInt(this.attemptQuestionSet)).then(function(questionSet){
        self.set('currentQuestionSet',questionSet); // <-- note use of stored reference
      },function(){
        alert("Question Set not found");
      });
    }
  }
});
```